# How to print exceptions on console? I am using TestNG and Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to see the exceptions on console. I am using TestNG with Maven as a build tool. I have defined my testng.xml in the Maven surefire plugin.

Comment: In which console? Why you cannot see them currently? Can you add more context?

Comment: @AlexeyR. On IDE console. The exceptions are displayed on the TestNG's tab under the test failure label.

Comment: This is a straight forward question ! why to close

Comment: Testng won't print the exception to stdout you have to handle it in a special way]

Comment: @AlexeyR. Please vote to reopen

Comment: Alright, voted. But I believe the proper answer has been already given. Unless there is some configuration feature that allows to override default behavior.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thank you  the answer which is provided is wrong , should use VerboseReporter

Comment: Please do vote to reopen so that i can add the answer

Comment: @shriv ☝️set your vote as well. I spent mine.

Comment: @PDHide ReOpened the question to accept additional answers.

Comment: @DebanjanB Added the answer thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/org/testng/reporters/VerboseReporter.html

you should use above reporter , but the constructor expects a string so you cannot initialize it using testng.xml **( if any one knows how to pass string argument to listener in testng.xml please do add it here )**

So the work around is to add  the listener through script and initiate testng through a java entry file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        TestNG testng = new TestNG();

        // Create a list of String
        List<String> suitefiles = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Add xml file which you have to execute
        suitefiles.add(prop.getProperty("path_to_your_existing_testngxml\testng.xml"));

        // now set xml file for execution
        testng.setTestSuites(suitefiles);
        
        testng.addListener(new VerboseReporter("[TestNG] "));

        // finally execute the runner using run method
        testng.run();

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note**

As this reporter constructor expects a string you should not provide it in your testng.xml you will get initialization error

Comment: Thanks @PDHide. I have added the listener of 'VerboseReporter' and now able to see the TestNG logs.

Comment: any idea of how to change the Verbose level?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: Also https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html search for verbose in this two documents

Comment: how can we define the verbose level programmatically?

Comment: testng.setVerbose(verbose);

Comment: Is there any workaround to display TestNG logs only in case of test failures or any exception?

Answer (score 3):

If you use any kind of logging framework you should probably stick with that.
Otherwise you can always print Exceptions using https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace() (and siblings) such as

```
...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
...
```